# Passing parameters from SL Reporting to Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, reporting

I am trying to figure out how to pass some of the options from Microsoft SL Reporting to my report in SQL Reporting Services. I need to use them as parameters for my SQL statement in the report and can not figure out how to accomplish the connection between the two programs.

During runtime, SL Reporting creates the RptRuntime table that the report can access through the RIParam function.  However, I can't figure out how to get access to that table from the SQL side.

Any help would be great!
Thanks much!

Comment: What is "Microsoft SL Reporting"?

Comment: Micosoft Dynamics SL Reporting, SL stands for Solomon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to send parameters to Reporting Services: query parameters and report parameters, [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155917(SQL.90).aspx) for details.